# Replace string by numerical value

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in data with

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'], header=None)
```

I get

```
df.dtypes
Out[54]: 
A     int64
B    object
C     int64
D     int64
E    object
F    object
G    object
H    object
I    object
J    object
K    object
dtype: object
```

The problem is that some of the fields in the original data have been replaced with the string SUPP when they are less than 6 (but more than 0) so I am not getting numerical data types. I tried replacing them with

```
df.replace('SUPP', 3.0)
```

but I still don't get numerical data types.

Some typical input data looks like

```
931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
931,Oxfordshire,9316076,123298,Our Lady's Abingdon,Abingdon,57,57,SUPP,SUPP,16
```

The problem can be reproduced by just saving the example above as file.csv.

Comment: Have you tried `df.replace('SUPP', 3.0, inplace=True)`?

Comment: @EdChum That also doesn't help. I still don't get numerical data types.

Comment: How about reading the values in as `NaN` like `df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'], header=None, na_values=['SUPP'])` this will replace 'SUPP' with `NaN` which you should be able to replace

Comment: @EdChum That works in the sense that you get the right data types but isn't what I want. I want to use the fact that the values are very small in the graph I will plot rather than just ignore them.

Comment: But you can replace `NaN` with 3.0 so it should achieve what you want no?

Comment: @EdChum Oh I see. That seems rather indirect but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EdChum almost had it in the comments.

```
In [18]: df.dtypes
Out[18]: 
0      int64
1     object
2      int64
3      int64
4     object
5     object
6      int64
7      int64
8     object
9     object
10     int64
dtype: object

In [19]: df.replace('SUPP', 3, inplace=True)

In [20]: df.dtypes
Out[20]: 
0      int64
1     object
2      int64
3      int64
4     object
5     object
6      int64
7      int64
8     object
9     object
10     int64
dtype: object

In [21]: df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [22]: df.dtypes
Out[22]: 
0      int64
1     object
2      int64
3      int64
4     object
5     object
6      int64
7      int64
8      int64
9      int64
10     int64
dtype: object
```

You need to `convert_objects` because even though you've replaced `SUPP` with 3, the other values in that column are still strings (object dtype).

Comment: That works thanks but I don't understand the explanation.  df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv", na_values=['SUPP'], names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'], header=None)  also gives the right data types so it can only be the SUPP values that cause the problem surely?

Comment: @felix because of the ambiguouity of the data type it thinks the data type is a string, if you tell it that 'SUPP' is NaN it can then parse the remaining data as numeric that is the real problem here

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. The remaining data for that column hasn't been parsed as being numeric.

Comment: Yeah. Each pandas column has a single dtype. As the parser goes along it sees the "SUPP" and assigns the dtype `object` (string) to that column. So every item in that column is a string. You can check by reading in `df` and doing `df.iloc[0]['J']` and seeing that it returns a string.